# Problem in understanding the proof of existence of a bijective function between a subset of Natural number and set of Natural number itself.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading this [pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ysella/Math115AHCardinality.pdf) where I came across this proposition and its proof:

> Proposition 2: Let $S \subset \mathbb N$ be an infinite subset. Then there exists a bijection between $S$ and $\mathbb N.$
>   Proof: You might think this is intuitively clear. But let’s prove it carefully.
>   We define a map $f : \mathbb N \rightarrow S$ as follows. Note that any nonempty subset
>   of the natural numbers has a least element (this is known as the well-ordering
>   principle). Since the set $S$ is infinite, it is nonempty. So we let $f(0)$ be the least
>   element in $S.$ We now define $f$ recursively as follows. Let $n \in  \mathbb N$ and assume
>   we have defined $f$ on all numbers less than or equal to n. Then we note that
>   the set $\{f(0), \ldots , f(n)\} \subset S$ is not equal to $S,$ or else $S$ would be finite. So the
>   complement $S − \{f(0), \ldots , f(n)\}$ is nonempty, and therefore has a least element.
>   Define $f(n + 1)$ to be this least element. By recursion, this defines f on all of $\mathbb N.$
>   We now argue that $f$ is a bijection. The injectivity of $f$ follows from the fact
>   that, by construction, $f(n)$ differs from $f(m)$ for all $m < n.$ To show $f $ is a surjection,
>   suppose not. Then there exists $x \in S$ which is not in the image of $f.$
>   But this implies $x \geq f(n)$ for all $n$ (because if $x$ were smaller than $f(n)$ then by
>   construction it must be of the form $f(m)$ for some $m < n$). However, **we know that
>   each $f(n) \geq n$ for each $n$** so we conclude $x \geq f(n) \geq n $for each $n.$ In particular
>   $x \geq x + 1,$ a contradiction. So $f$ is in fact surjective, so it is a bijection.

While I could get the proof, I couldn't comprehend how the author concluded $f(n)\geq n$ for each $n\,.$

Could anyone help me explaining why "*each $f(n) \geq n$ for each $n$*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B=\{n\in\Bbb N:f(n)<n\}$. If there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(n)<n$, then $B\ne\varnothing$, so $B$ has a least element $m$. Clearly $m>0$ (why?), so $m=k+1$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$. Then $k\notin B$, so $f(k)\ge k$. But $f(m)<m$, so $f(m)\le k$, and therefore $f(m)\le f(k)$, contradicting the construction of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sir. As for _why?_, my answer would be $0$ is not present in $\mathbb N\,.$ And you chose $m = k+1$ as $\mathbb N$ is inductive ensuring the presence of $k$ in $\mathbb N\,.$ Could you tell how you wrote $f(m)\leq k\,?$ I'm not getting that. I have $m\gt k; ~ f(k)\geq k$ and $f(m)\lt m$ given, if I'm right.

Comment: Also, why does $k$ not belong to $B\,?$ Is it because, $m$ is _the_ (you have written _a_; so I'm confused) least element/smallest element of $B$ and $k\lt m$ and thus $k\notin B\,?$

Comment: @MAFIA36790: Although some people do use $\Bbb N$ for the set of positive integers, others, including me and the author of that proof, use it for the set of non-negative integers. You can tell that the author does: you're told that $f$ is a function whose domain is $\Bbb N$, and then you're told what $f(0)$ is. Clearly this makes sense only if $0\in\Bbb N$. But there is still a reason that $0\notin B$; what is it? \\ You have $m=k+1$ and $f(m)<m$, so $f(m)<k+1$. But $f(m)$ is an integer, and $k$ is the largest integer less than $k+1$, so $f(m)\le k$.

Comment: @MAFIA36790: The fact that $B$ has a *unique* smallest element does not make it incorrect to say that it has *a* smallest element. It would in fact be incorrect English to say '$B\ne\varnothing$, so $B$ has the smallest element'.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $f(0)\ge 0$.
By the recursion procedure, we have $f(n+1)>f(n)$, i.e., $f(n+1)\ge f(n)+1$ and using the induction hypothesis $ f(n)\ge  n$, we find $f(n+1)\ge n+1$.

Comment: Thanks, sir, for the answer. However, could you please elaborate how you wrote $f(n+1)\geq f(n)+1$ and $f(n+1)\gt f(n)\,?$

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Note that $A>B$ means $A\ge B+1$ (assuming $A$ and $B$ are both integers), so "$\ge$" expression follows from the "$>$" expression. How do we know $f(n+1)>f(n)$? Look at the definition of $f$ - $f(n+1)$ is the least element of $S\setminus{f(0), f(1), . . . , f(n)}$ . . .

Comment: Thanks @Noah for the comment. The range of $f$ is in $\mathbb N$ and now that $f(n+1)\gt f(n),$ we can get $f(n+1)-f(n)\geq 1\,.$